# How can i solve reindex error

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i solve the reindex problem
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the steps listed here: http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process-in-index-management-in-magento/

You can also try re-indexing by CLI commands. Go to `shell` directory and run following commands:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

For re-indexing All indexes:

```
php -f indexer.php reindexall
```

From your screenshot, it seems there's `Search Index` indexer issue, for this truncate `catalogsearch_fulltext`, `catalogsearch_query` and `catalogsearch_result` tables. Then try indexing, but Take a **backup first**

Comment: am also try this, but not work

Comment: Take a database **backup** and truncate `catalogsearch_fulltext`, `catalogsearch_query` and `catalogsearch_result` tables. Then try indexing

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b6mhk7

Comment: truncate or what ??

Comment: Empty = Truncate

Comment: http://prnt.sc/b6midp

Comment: when i try to  this catalogsearch_query, i got this error

Comment: May you know this error....

Comment: first truncate `catalogsearch_fulltext` and `catalogsearch_result`. Then do Browse `catalogsearch_query` > Select all rows > click Delete

Comment: ok, let me do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40093/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-anil-suthar).

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your issue is due to the products which are creating hindrance in the Index process.

You have to run the below queries for re-indexing to work:

```
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_gallery` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
#originals with formatting fixed:
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE category_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_category_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_website` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_link` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_relation` WHERE parent_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
```

> backup your database before run sql query.

Hope this helps you out

Comment: are u still online, i have doubt

Comment: yes tell me wt is?

Comment: can i run all the commands what you gave,

Comment: yes it solve my issue. but please take backup of your database.

Comment: :: Take a database backup and truncate catalogsearch_fulltext, catalogsearch_query and catalogsearch_result tables. Then try indexing...

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: using this or other solution you do?

Comment: Am just shared let you know other options exists, This solutions am used to solve the problem,  
:: Take a database backup and truncate catalogsearch_fulltext, catalogsearch_query and catalogsearch_result tables. Then try indexing...

Comment: oh that nice...!!!